# Heroku Stripe Invalid API Key provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

I keep receiving the error on heroku even though the key is correct.

This doesn't work:

```
if Rails.env.production?
 Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY']
 STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
```

Yet this with the same key does:

```
if Rails.env.production?
 Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY']
 STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'pk_key'
```

I figured the Heroku env key was incorrect but I have reentered it and they are identical. I can't figure out why it won't work unless I put the key itself in.

Comment: Have you tried to log the `ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']` to see what the application sees `Rails.logger.warn("### PUBLIC KEY IS #{ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'].inspect}")` or something

Comment: You could try to print out the key to the log to make sure that it is using the right one...

Comment: Just did and checked the logs and it is correct. Still getting the same error and I can't find any reason for it. Again if I just make the one change and specify the pk_key instead it works.